# Apache Flex 4.8.0 not working in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: apache, apache-flex, flash-builder

Yesterday, I started using Apache Flex 4.8.0 in my Flash Builder 4.6. Everything works fine, thanks to a tutorial on http://lucamezzalira.com/2012/07/24/how-to-install-flex-4-8-0-sdk-in-flash-builder/
Now, I downloaded the beta of Flash Builder 4.7. The release notes state that Apache Flex 4.8.0 is supported. However, when I try to add it to my SDK list, it says "directory does not contain a flex sdk". I have no other options whatsoever. I just did the same as in the tutorial. what's wrong=

Comment: 1./ FB4.7 is a beta product  2./As I understand it, you need to build Apache Flex in a specific way to make it work with FB4.6. The requirements may very well have changed for FB4.7

Comment: I have used Apache Flex 4.8 w/ FB 4.7 .  I strongly suggest you use the software tool being created by the Apache Flex Team to prep the SDK for use w/ Flash Builder: http://people.apache.org/~bigosmallm/installapacheflex_RC5/ .  As I understand it the FB4.7 support for Apache Flex means they fixed some bugs w/ the multi-SDK feature; but no one has been able to deliver details; so it sounds more like a marketing claim than a reality decision.